# RecyclerView com o botão mostrar mais

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Possuo um recyclerview que puxa dados do firebase, porém ele pega todos os dados de uma vez só, e isso faz com que o aplicativo trave, como eu faço para ele mostrar só os 10 primeiros e conforme o usuario for descendo o scrool ele vá baixando mais dados?

Adapter

```
  public VideoListAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, @LayoutRes 
  int resource, @NonNull List<VideoUpload> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.image_item, objects);
    this.context = context;
    listImage = objects;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);

    imgList = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Videos/");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            //Fetch image data from firebase database
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                VideoUpload video = snapshot.getValue(VideoUpload.class);
                string = video.getUrl();


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    telefone = v.findViewById(R.id.contatoResponsavel);
    posicao = v.findViewById(R.id.posicaoJogador);
    idade = v.findViewById(R.id.idadeJogador);
    localidade = v.findViewById(R.id.localidadeJogador);
    TextView tvName = v.findViewById(R.id.tvImageName);
    imgYoutube = v.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);

    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) v.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);

    String tvNameString;
    final String linkFormatado;
    final String linkYoutube;
    linkYoutube = listImage.get(position).getUrl();

    linkFormatado = linkYoutube.replace("https://youtu.be/", "");
    posicao.setText("Posição: " + listImage.get(position).getPosicao());
    idade.setText("Idade: " + listImage.get(position).getIdade());
    localidade.setText("Localização: " + listImage.get(position).getEstado());
    tvNameString = listImage.get(position).getName();
    telefone.setText("Contato: " + listImage.get(position).getTelefone());

    tvName.setText("Nome: " + tvNameString);
    imgYoutube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) getContext(),
                    "AIzaSyBvrGBKv7AU19B8DPp9ubiWPRS9FE7Ek9w",
                    linkFormatado,

                    100,
                    true,
                    false);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


    return v;
}


}
```

Activity

```
    container = findViewById(R.id.container);

    anim = (AnimationDrawable) container.getBackground();
    anim.setEnterFadeDuration(2500);
    anim.setExitFadeDuration(5000);
    anim.start();


    imgList = new ArrayList<>();

   lv = findViewById(R.id.listViewImage);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation2 = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation2.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Aguarde ....");
    progressDialog.show();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Videos/");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //Fetch image data from firebase database
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //ImageUpload class require default constructor
                VideoUpload video = snapshot.getValue(VideoUpload.class);
                imgList.add(video);


            }


            adapter = new VideoListAdapter(HomeJogadorActivity.this, R.layout.image_item, imgList);
            //Set adapter for listview
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o **setHasFixedSize()** para o recycler view isso ajuda com o ganho de performance de acordo com a documentação.

Exemplo:

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

Java Doc:

RecyclerView can perform several optimizations if it can know in advance that RecyclerView's size is not affected by the adapter contents. RecyclerView can still change its size based on other factors (e.g. its parent's size) but this size calculation cannot depend on the size of its children or contents of its adapter (except the number of items in the adapter).

If your use of RecyclerView falls into this category, set this to {@code true}. It will allow RecyclerView to avoid invalidating the whole layout when its adapter contents change.

@param hasFixedSize true if adapter changes cannot affect the size of the RecyclerView.

Depois me fale se deu certo, abraços.